# Definition of surjective - understanding notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In *Measures, Integrals and Martingales* by René L. Schilling surjective (or onto) is defined as:

$$f(X) := \{f(x) \in Y\,:\,x\in X\} = Y$$

I think I understand the concept of surjective in a function $X \rightarrow Y$, but I am stuck with the notation. How can I read from left to right the math line above? In particular I am inquiring about:

1. $:=$ Is it "defined as..."? If so, what are we defining?
2. $:$ Is the colon read as "such that"?
3. $=$ Is $X = Y$? It wouldn' make sense, would it? The first is in the domain, while the second in the range of the function.
4. The use of upper and lower case. In this regard, notice how he defines an injective mapping:

$$f(x) = f(x')\Rightarrow x= x'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f$ is assumed to be a function from $X$ to $Y$.  $X$ is the domain, $Y$ is the codomain, which does not have to be the same as $X$.
This statement can be unpacked as follows:

1. $f(X)$ is defined to be the set of $f(x)$ (which is a member of $Y$) for all $x$ in $X$.
2. $f$ is surjective if $f(X) = Y$, i.e. every member of $Y$ must be $f(x)$ for some $x$ in $X$.

BTW,  [René Schilling](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schilling/) is a he, not a she.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between upper and lower case? Is it like a random variable $X$ versus its realized values $x_i$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are sets, $x$ and $y$ are members of those sets.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is defined in two steps.

First we define the image of a function $f : X \to Y$. The image of $f$, noted $f(X)$ is defined by $$f(X) := \{f(x) : x \in X\}.$$ Note that many people don't like the notation $:=$ and simply use the equality.

Now we can define the concept of surjection. A function $f : X \to Y$ is surjection if $$f(X) = Y.$$ In other words, for each $y \in Y$ you can find $x \in X$ such that $f(x) =y$.

Answer (score 1):

The image $f(X)$ of $f$ is defined to be the set of points $f(x)$ in $Y$, where $x$ ranges over all of $X$. The function $f$ is **surjective** if this image $f(X)$ is all of $Y$, which is to say each $y$ in $Y$ is given as $f(x)$ for some $x$ in $X$.

**added**: the middle colon in the set means "such that." I have added some set braces to make your question clearer; because braces group things in TeX, you need a backslash before each to make them display. You are correct that "$:=$" is used to write "is defined as."

Comment: I don't mind at all your editing the OP, but please note that I was trying to copy verbatim the text in the book.

Comment: I see. In the code of the OP, as I saw when I checked, there were braces, but LaTeX uses braces without preceding backslashes for grouping and does not display them. I assumed the braces were meant to be displayed, but failed, so added two backslashes in an attempt to restore the question to what I thought was the intended form. Without them, the expression is indeed very difficult to understand, but I assumed this was a coding error on your part rather than a faithful rendition of the apparent (odd) bracelessness of the original book. My apologies.

Comment: No, you were correct, I just forgot the \ in front of the }.